# (PHP) Why does this generator-script adds the starting value + the step-value to the starting value?

Tags: php, loops, variables, math, foreach

the title may be pretty confusing. Here's a script which requires a start-end and step value to add numbers to the start value:

```
function addieren($start, $ende, $schritt = 1) {
        if ($start < $ende) {
          $erg = 0;
          for ($i = $start; $i <= $ende; $i += $schritt) {
            $erg += $i;
            yield $erg;
          }
        }
      }

      foreach (addieren(2, 10, 2) as $erg) {
        echo $erg . "<br>";
      }
```

So the start value is 2, the end value is 10 (but it's not ending at 10 as the result shows), and it should add 2 to the $i every step.

Here's the output:

```
      2
      6
      12
      20
      30
```

The first output is clear to me, since the `$erg` was 0 and it added the 2 because of 2 steps.

But the next output is 6 and I don't get why. In the second loop, `$i` is 2 and and the script says: `$i += $schritt` so when `$i` is 2 and the `$schritt` value is also 2, why doesn't that output 4 as the second output? Hope you get what I mean.. I guess it's a pure logic error in my head.

Comment: And also.. why does it even loop behind 12? The end-vaue is 10, I don't get that..

Comment: What's the expected result? 2,4,6,8,10?

Comment: "_why doesn't that output 4 as the second output?_" Because `$erg` is 2 and 4 gets added

Comment: @kerbholz It's a script from a book and the book-result is the result I displayed in the question, but I don't get why. I think it should be 2,4,6,8,10.

Comment: Ohh.. I got it.. thank you. I should take a break haha

Comment: I think the confusion here is because `$erg` retains its state between yielded values, so it increases by larger amounts each time. The

Comment: @iainn Yes.. so $i increases by 2 every loop, and $erg gets bigger and bigger.